# How to add the numbers inside the scanf in loop?

Tags: c, loops, scanf, do-while

Is there some way to add all the numbers in a `scanf` loop? The loop would stop if the input number is negative. The problem is that the negative must also be included in the sum.

Here, I managed to get the sum of all the *positive* `scanf` values repeated in the loop, but the *negative* number is still not included in the sum of all the numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int z, x;

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    z = 0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    do
    {
        z += x;
        scanf(" %d", &x);
    } while (x >= 0);
    printf("Sum = %d ", z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when the input is `foo`?  You *must* check the value returned by `scanf`.

Comment: Why 2 `scanf`? Remove first and move `z += x;` after `scanf`. And remove the space in `" %d"`.

Comment: oh, that solved my problem, THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I don't know why I added that scanf on the first. maybe I was solving it for hours I forgot I added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple rearrangement of the order of statements in your `do ... while` loop (and removal of the preceding `scanf` call) will do the trick:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main() // You are returning "0" so declare "int" as return type
{
    int x = 0, z = 0;   // Easier to initialize at the same time as declaration.
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
//  scanf ("%d", &x);   // Don't read here - do that inside the loop.
    do {
        int test = scanf(" %d", &x);  // Read as the FIRST statement in the loop ...
        if (test != 1) { // If the "scanf" call failed, we need to clear the input stream ...
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                ; // Clear any offending input
            if (c == EOF) break; // Probably can't recover from an EOF, so exit the while loop
        }
        else z += x;                  // ... then we can add X even if it's negative
    } while (x >= 0);                 // But end the loop when it IS negative anyway

    printf("Sum = %d ", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have added a `test` variable to makes sure that the `scanf` operation succeeded. If the usser enters `foo` (as mentioned in the comment by William Pursell), then the input buffer is cleared, the addition is skipped, and the read will be attempted again.

Comment: What about `if (test != 1) continue;` and `while (x >= 0);`? UB.

Comment: @i486 Good point and well spotted. Initialization of `x = 0` should fix that (see edit).

Comment: @anastaciu Indeed. I improved the error handling (in a similar manner to how you did).

Answer (score 2):

Inverting the lines inside the loop should do it:

```
int z, x;
int ch;

printf("Enter a number:\n");
z = 0;
do
{
    if (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) // checking if parsing was successful
    {
        z += x; // if so, perform the sum
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Bad input");                             // if user inputs a bad value
        while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF){} // you clear the input buffer
    }

} while (x >= 0);
printf("Sum = %d ", z);
```

Note that I also removed the first scanf ouside the loop, which becomes unneeded.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you want to handle an input stream that does not contain a negative value as an error, but you could simply do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int sum = 0, x, rv;
    while( 1 == (rv = scanf ("%d", &x)) ){
        sum += x;
        if( x < 0 ){
            break;
        }
    }
    if( rv == 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
    } else {
        printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);
    }
    return rv == 0 ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I think the following behavior is reasonable:

```
$ echo 4 5 8 5| ./a.out
Sum = 22
$ echo 4 5 -1 5| ./a.out
Sum = 8
$ echo 4 5 not-an-integer 5| ./a.out
Invalid input
```